# Mongodb query selecting using document's field

Tags: mongodb

I have the query:

```
.find({$where: 'this.lastEmailDate < Date.now() - this.warnTime'})
```

This is a very slow operation. Is there a way to convert this query to use $lt?

I have seen that some people have suggested creating a new variable and selecting using that, but the issue is that Date.now() is constantly changing.

Comment: How about using aggregation with  `$redact`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the operation is slow because of the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator which has pretty bad performance issues. The reason being that when you perform a normal (non-**[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)**) query, your client converts the query to BSON and sends that to the db and since MongoDB stored its data as BSON, the queries would be faster as it esssentially compares the query directly against the data.

Now with a **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator query, MongoDB first creates a JavaScript object for every document in collection, then parses the documents' BSON and adds all the fields to the JS objects. It will then execute the JS you sent against the documents and then tears it all down again - this is very resource-intensive operation hence the slow queries with the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** clause.

---

Now, the best approach would be to leverage the query with the aggregation framework. Consider the following pipeline which does exactly the same query but much faster and thus better performance:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": { 
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$eq": [ 
                        { "$comp": [ 
                            "$lastEmailDate", 
                             { "$subtract": [new Date(), "$warnTime"] }
                        ]}, 
                        -1 
                    ] 
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

---

The above uses the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** operator which essentially restricts the contents of the documents based on information stored in the documents themselves.

Depending on the expression that it feeds into, it resolves to query the collection by evaluates the fields using the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** logical operator. Within the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator, you can use the **[`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/#exp._S_eq)** an the **[`$cmp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/#exp._S_cmp)** with the $subtract operators do carry out the logic:

If the result of the **[`$cmp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/#exp._S_cmp)** operation is -1, then display return the whole document (at document level) else )
The **[`$cmp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/#exp._S_cmp)** expression will evaluate to -1 if `lastEmailDate` is less that the result when the `warnTime` is subtracted from the `current` date

Comment: This perfect. Thank you so much for this.